# How to remove a CSS class property using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove the display:block property in the given css class using javascript.

This is the Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.abc{
display:block;
color:green;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:Underline;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The removeProperty() Method</h1>

<p class="abc">Click the button to remove the color property.</p>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Remove Property it</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  var d1 = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
  d1.style.removeProperty('display');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

not able to achieve!
Did I miss something?

Comment: You could try dynamically changing the class of the element, or overwriting the style dynamically as two alternative solutions.

Comment: Note that `display: block` is a CSS style, not a class.

Comment: Also does getElementsByClassName return an array-like, HTMLCollection?

Comment: To solve the problem presented in my previous comment your variable `d1` is actually an HTMLCollection not an element so we need to loop through the HTMLCollection which is for many purposes just like an array. `for(const element of d1) {...}` then we need to perform the same operation on each element in the array `element.removeProperty...`

Comment: I understand, I tried looping too..
```function myFunction1() {

   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.removeProperty('color');
   
}
}
```
but still not able to achieve it. Am i going wrong somewhere!